# Program crashing due to IOException

Tags: c#, file-handling, ioexception

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to create a simple program that asks the user to input a filename and some text to then be saved to the newly created file. Maybe I went too fast and did not learn everything I should have about file manipulation. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter name of file then add .txt");
var fileName = Console.ReadLine();

var folderPath = @"C:\Users\Treppy\Desktop\Megatest\";
var filePath = folderPath + fileName;
File.Create(filePath);


Console.WriteLine(filePath);

Console.WriteLine("Enter the text you want to save to that file");
var inputTextUser = Console.ReadLine();

File.AppendAllText(filePath, inputTextUser);
```

When the application crashes on line 29, I get this message:

> System.IO.IOException the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Line 29 which is the `AppendAllText` line.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The application crashes

Comment: How do it crush? What exception is thrown? At which line?

Comment: system.IO.IOException the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. Line 29 wich is the appendAllText line.

Comment: Please post the error you get *in the question itself*, not in a comment

Comment: place it inside a `try-catch` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you (your application) still "hold" that file. Actualy, you don't need to create that file, before you write something to it. As stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file.appendalltext(v=vs.110).aspx) `AppendAllText` will create a file, if it does not exists, so just remove that line, where `File.Create(filePath);`

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code like as

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter name of file then add .txt");
            var fileName = Console.ReadLine();

            var folderPath =  @"C:\Users\Treppy\Desktop\Megatest\";
            var filePath = folderPath + fileName;


            Console.WriteLine(filePath);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the text you want to save to that file");
            string[] lines = new string[1];
            var inputTextUser = Console.ReadLine();
            lines[0] = inputTextUser;

            //File.AppendAllText(filePath, inputTextUser);
            File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines);
```

You can write without array

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath, inputTextUser);
```

Comment: again, `AppendAllText` and `WriteAllLines` will work the same for new empty file

Comment: It works, Thank you so much! it makes more sense that way. still learning. :)

Comment: @MarcTrep Did you learn what mistake you did? I think you are interested in solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close/dispose the previous stream that accessed the file because `File.Create` keeps the file open and returns a `FileStream` object.

I checked your code and this solution works.

```
File.Create(filePath).Close();
```

**OR/AND**

```
File.Create(filePath).Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `File.Create` method keeps the file opened thus the Operating System puts a lock on it. The method returns a `FileStream` object you can use for read/write access. Before you can write to that file with a different method (such as `File.WriteAllText` - this method will try to open an already opened file), the `FileStream` object must be first disposed. See this [MS reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx).

Simply commenting out that line of code will fix the `IOException`.

In general, `File.Create` is not a very commonly used method and is generally used in more specialized cases. If possible, the prefered way is to construct your text file in memory using a `string` or a `StringBuilder` then output the contents to file. In your case, that is definitely the approach you want to take. As others have mentioned, you would use `File.WriteAllText`. It will create the file if it does not exist, or replace the contents of the already existing file. If you want to keep previous content, the use `File.AppendAllText` as you did in your question. This method will create the file if it does not exist or append the text to the end of the previous content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter name of file then add .txt");
var fileName = Console.ReadLine();

var folderPath = @"C:\Users\Treppy\Desktop\Megatest\";

var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName);

if (!File.Exists(filePath))
{
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, "");
}

Console.WriteLine(filePath);

Console.WriteLine("Enter the text you want to save to that file");
var inputTextUser = Console.ReadLine();

File.AppendAllText(filePath, inputTextUser);
```

That'll stop the `File.Create` holding the file open with the OS.